# How to save data in a NSObject

Tags: ios, nsobject

I'm using Restkit to return a bunch of objects when a users presses log-in. I need to store these different objects and properties in a custom NSObject for reference throughout the app.

I'm no genius at Objc, which is why I'll need an example and explanation of what I'm doing wrong. SO doesn't have any examples for custom NSObjects which is why I'm asking here.

Thanks in advance, I'll be sure to accept the correct answer.

In the loginViewController I have this to set the array in the custom NSObject:

```
Crap *crapper = [[Crap alloc] init];
        [crapper setCrapArray:array];
```

This the the Crap.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Crap : NSObject <NSCoding> 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *crapArray;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)enCoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;

@end
```

And the Crap.m:

```
#import "Crap.h"

@implementation Crap

@synthesize crapArray;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.crapArray forKey:@"crapArray"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.crapArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"crapArray"];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I'm using this to retrieve the data in the FeedViewController:

```
Crap *crap = [[Crap alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", crap.crapArray.count);
```

Which of course is 0 (array count is really 40 something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header Crap file should be

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Crap : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *crapArray;

+ (Crap *) crap;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)enCoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;

@end
```

Your implementation Crap file should be

```
#import "Crap.h"

@implementation Crap

@synthesize crapArray;

+ (Crap *) crap {
    static Crap *crap = nil;
    if (!crap) {
        crap = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    }

    return crap;
}

+ (id) allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone {
    return [self crap];
}

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // set default property values
        crapArray = nil;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.crapArray forKey:@"crapArray"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.crapArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"crapArray"];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then to set the value you got to do something like

```
[Crap crap].crapArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello", @"Bye", nil];
```

And to get that value from another view controller you got to do something like

```
NSLog(@"Value: %d", [[Crap crap] crapArray].count);
```

If you do

```
Crap *crap = [[Crap alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", crap.crapArray.count);
```

crapArray will be set to nil and you are going to get 0 again, because we are setting crapArray to nil on the init method.

Comment: Great answer, i think it will solve my problem. Possibly could you tell me that it's possible to refresh crap array inside of an another view controller again and again? Or it will store the value for the whole lifecycle?

Comment: It's possible to refresh crap array inside another view controller again and again, just try it and don't forget to import Crap file in the view controller in which you want to refresh the array

Answer (score 0):

startObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface startObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *crapArray;

@end
```

startObject.m

## import "startObject.h"

```
@implementation startObject

@synthesize crapArray;


- (id)init {

    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
@end
```

Use:

```
startObject* start = [[startObject alloc] init];

start.crapArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alpha", @"Beta", @"Gamma", @"Omega", nil];

NSLog(@"%@",start.crapArray);
```

Result:

```
(
Alpha,
Beta,
Gamma,
Omega
)
```

The above code is used to save data to an NSObject. That's it.
To release it's contents, you simply set `start = nil`.

But if you are looking to save data to disk using Archiving, let me know. Also look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data) for a detailed tutorial on using `NSCoding`.

Comment: I asked for a code example & all you provided is the code I already had. Can't accept that.

Comment: Just one thing, do you only want to save data in an NSObject (for use during lifetime), or do you need an archiver/encoder to save data to disk ?